# What to do when Broken pipe happens in pssh where one output file is expected at each host, and process is still running

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a command that connects to different remote machines and executes a script. I do this by using:

```
pssh -h pssh-hosts -l username -A -t 0 -i "bash -x commands.sh".
```

There are many hosts in the host file.  At the host, a computation intensive code is run and o/p file is generated, this may take 6 hours or more. While running  I get:

```
./test
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Does it make sense to wait for the process to finish or does broken pipe mean the output files (at other the remote hosts) will not be written?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not enough info at the moment to get real leverage on this.

Does the script produce a run log on each machine? If not, probably worth modifying it to make it do so. (Ensure that STDERR as well as STDIN goes into the log.)

One thing which occurs to me from the messages - "./test" implies that something is using relative paths: it would be worth going through the script, and changing it to use absolute paths everywhere. (If utilities on the target machines are in different places due to differing distros, include a test, and construct the absolute path dynamically.)